# Delete Entity in Many to Many Relation. Don't get error but entity is not deleted

Tags: entity-framework

I have, in EF5, two entities: User and Role.

Between User and Role there is a many to many relation.

I don't have an entity for the UserRoles database which sets the relation.

I have a User and I want to delete a role without loading it from the database.

```
  Context context = new Context();
  User user = context.Users.First(x => x.Id == 4);
  user.Roles = new List<Role>();
  Role role = new Role { Id = 20 };
  context.Roles.Attach(role);
  user.Roles.Remove(role);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

I don't get any error but the role is not removed.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are removing `role` from `user.Roles` but `role` is not in this list, so nothing happens.

I think you have to attach the user *and* the role at once to the context so that change detection can recognize a change of the object graph when you remove the role:

```
Context context = new Context();

User user = new User { Id = 4 };
user.Roles = new List<Role>();
Role role = new Role { Id = 20 };
user.Roles.Add(role)

context.Users.Attach(user);

user.Roles.Remove(role);

context.SaveChanges();
```